# How to get ranks based on power BI report views

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get ranks based on the views count on reports in workspaces.I tried so many ways and can someone help me to get the ranks based on the view count.I got views,

```
viewS = IF(Usage[Activity]="ViewReport"|| Usage[Activity]="ViewDashboard",1,0)
View count= CALCULATE(COUNT(Usage[viewS]))
```

I want to get ranks based on the view count. Can someone correct me if my view count KPI is wrong? and also help me to get the ranks.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use RANKX formula to get the ranking. The measure for ranking should be something like that:

```
Rank = RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( Usage[ReportId] ), CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Usage[viewS] ) ) )
```

Here you can see function parameters and a couple examples: https://databear.com/how-to-use-the-dax-rankx-function-in-power-bi/